# Opencart : 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, opencart, php-ini

I have [Opencart Store](http://usacompaniesdata.com/demo) and have an error on the front page. I can access the backend as well.

You will get below error after loading the page:

```
504 Gateway Time-out

The server didn't respond in time.
```

I'm giving my [php.ini](http://usacompaniesdata.com/demo/info.php) configuration help me to solve out.
Please suggest me `php.ini` changes by editing `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

**504 Gateway Timeout error on Nginx + FastCGI (php-fpm)**

For Nginx + FastCGI (php-fpm), you should try to tweak nginx configuration in this way:

Try raising max_execution_time setting in php.ini file (CentOS path is /etc/php.ini):

`max_execution_time = 300`

But, you should also change set request_terminate_timeout parameter (commented by default) at www.conf file from PHP-FPM:

```
pico -w /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Then set the variable to the same value as max_execution_time:

```
request_terminate_timeout = 300
```

Now let’s add fastcgi_read_timeout variable inside our Nginx virtual host configuration:

```
location ~ .php$ {
root /var/www/sites/nginxtips.com;
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

Then restart nginx:

service nginx reload
504 Gateway Timeout error using Nginx as Proxy
For Nginx as Proxy for Apache web server, this is what you have to try to fix the 504 Gateway Timeout error:

Add these variables to nginx.conf file:

```
 proxy_connect_timeout       600;
  proxy_send_timeout          600;
  proxy_read_timeout          600;
  send_timeout                600;
```

Then restart nginx:

service nginx reload

Comment: Hello Keshar It's Apache server